# Trying to implement strlen in x86 GAS

Tags: x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

so I am very new (extremely new) to assembly programming and am trying to write a function that can calculate the length of a string.

I feel I have some issue with clearing out values in registers, or with the incrementation of the pointer, because the value that is getting returned is always "4571 + length" for me.

Basically, if I have string length 0, I get 4571 as the return value.
If I have string length 6, I get 4577 as the return value, etc.

Here's my code, any help will be appreciated:

```
.globl my_strlen
    my_strlen:
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp
        pushq %r12
        pushq %r13

        movq $0, %rax
        cmp $0, (%rdi)
        jne my_strlen_loop
        ret

    my_strlen_loop:
        inc %rax
        inc %rdi
        cmp $0, (%rdi)
        jne my_strlen_loop

        popq %r13
        popq %r12
        popq %rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Add this right before the “ret”: “sub $4571, %rax”

Comment: That is more a temporary fix though. Why is 4571 getting into rax in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, it was a joke. :-) I’m writing a real answer.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with registers other than RAX and RDI.  Just leave R12 and R13 alone.  Also RBP, you have no need for a legacy stack frame.

Comment: That was just given to us as part of skeleton code. I know I do not need the three registers but I just left it that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

First, the `cmp` instructions don’t specify a size, and neither operand is a register, so it's ambiguous.  For most instructions (like `mov $0, (%rdi)`), GAS would refuse to assemble it, but `cmp` for some reason assembles to `cmpl`, comparing a dword.  Change the mnemonic to `cmpb` explicitly.

Second, before the first ret, it doesn’t pop the registers that were pushed. It would be better to jump to the end (and have a single ret).

Comment: The reason it returns 4571 is simply because that is the first place in your program’s data that it found 4 contiguous 0 bytes so the cmp matched.

Comment: It didn't refuse to assemble it. Changing the 'cmp' to 'cmpb' did the trick! Thank you very much, and I added a label to do the popping and returning. Thank you again.

Comment: @Suhas and prl:  My mistake, I thought I knew what GAS would do there, but for some reason `cmp` is different from `mov $0, (%rdi)`, and does assemble to dword `cmp`.  I'd consider it a bug to *not* error on that, and assemble that silently without at least a warning.

Comment: I agree, that seems like a bug in gas.